# Javafx application cannot find the liberay

Tags: java, javafx

In my eclipse i have followed the following steps:

1. New  -> Other -> Javafx project
2. Name the project i.e "TestJavaFx"
3. Create new class "Main"

write the following code:

```
    public class Main extends Application{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And i get an error saying:

```
Application cannot be resolved to a type
```

And there is no import.

it looks like i don't have the lib. But how can i create a new Javafx project without having the lib?

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

First in Eclipse you need add **jfxrt.jar** to project's libraries (It is located in Jre lib folder).

Then you need to override Application's abstract method start

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not needed because e(fx)clipse takes care of locating the jfxrt.jar